# Align container at the end in a row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `Row` with several widgets, I need to fill the whole row.

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      child: Text('To'),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Text('Container 2 widget'),
    ),
    Container(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('Cc'),
        onPressed: (){},
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('button2'),
        onPressed: (){},
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I need the last widget to be at `0` margin from right in the row and first widget to be at `0` margin from left.

Answer (score 0):

In `Row`, add this property:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, 
  children: [...],
)
```

You also don't need to use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`, it is already set to this value by default.

Comment: Thanks but my question is more complicated than this, I don't want the the widgets to have space between them. The edges of the widgets should touch as it's defined in the question. Any way to set width to be auto or something?

Comment: Found a solution. I wrapped the widgets in Exapanded widget.